# Yii2 KCFinder with CKEditor

Tags: yii2

I'm using KCFinder from [Iutbay/KCFinder](https://github.com/iutbay/yii2-kcfinder/) with CKEditor from [2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget). But KCFinder not work properly, it always show message "**You don't have permission....**"

I've read both of documentation but still not work.

this is my _view following iutbay's documentation:

```
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor; 
use iutbay\yii2kcfinder\KCFinderInputWidget;
use iutbay\yii2kcfinder\KCFinder;

$kcfOptions = array_merge(KCFinder::$kcfDefaultOptions, [
    'uploadURL' => Yii::getAlias('@web').'/upload',
    'disabled'=> false,
    'access' => [
        'files' => [
            'upload' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'copy' => true,
            'move' => true,
            'rename' => true,
        ],
        'dirs' => [
            'create' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'rename' => true,
        ],
    ],
]);

// Set kcfinder session options
Yii::$app->session->set('KCFINDER', $kcfOptions);
echo $form->field($model, 'images')->widget(KCFinderInputWidget::className(), [
    'multiple' => true,

]);
```

Comment: Please show us the complete error message and where do you see it ? And you don't need CKEditor if you use KCFinderInputWidget.

Answer (score 0):

**1- you does not have permission to upload picture into destination folder (upload)**
give full permission to (upload) folder, you can either do using your web server or you can using this command
sudo chmod -R 0777 kcfinder/upload

**2- go to the kcfinder folder and then find (config.php) find**

'disabled' => true
change it to
'disabled' => false